# Can we do Azure site recovery without any back-up?

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault, azure-site-recovery

Can we get Recovery point retention and app consistent snapshot while doing ASR if i did not set up any back up vault while configuring the VM in first place?

While ASR we get options for recovery point replication and app consistent snapshot options....are these recovery points and snapshots are the back-ups we create while creating VM ?

Answer (score 0):

Back up and ASR are different things, to enable ASR you don't need any previous backup points. All you need is a vault in azure, a configuration/process server on premises. Once you enable replication, it will get a snap shot of your disk as the initial replication. After that the crash/app consistent snap shots are taken and replicated to the disk in azure.

I may have miss understood your question, so if that's not the answer you were looking for, clarify please

Answer (score 0):

Azure Site Recovery is used for mainly 2 purposes- For DR and For Migration.

For both, replication is required and back-up for on-prem is not mandatory (if you have it, it is good). Recovery points and app-consistent snapshots will be generated anyhow post complete replication. Though app-consistent snapshots also depend on VSS installed on source machine.